# Consulta Hibernate (HQL) em Java com chave estrangeira... ERRO!

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, chave-estrangeira, hql

Estou precisando de ajuda com meu código, tenho duas tabelas:
-CDF (cadastro de funcionário)

```
CREATE TABLE public.cdf(
    ativo character varying(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    reg integer NOT NULL,
    nome character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    senha character varying(33) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cdf_pkey PRIMARY KEY (reg)
)
```

-RGPT (Registro de Ponto) com 2 Chaves estrangeiras de CDF: `reg`-> número do registro e `nome`

```
CREATE TABLE public.rgpt(
    id_rgpt integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('rgpt_id_rgpt_seq'::regclass),
    reg integer NOT NULL,
    nome character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    entrada character varying(5) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    saida character varying(5) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT rgpt03_pkey1 PRIMARY KEY (id_rgpt),
        CONSTRAINT rgpt_fk FOREIGN KEY (reg)
        REFERENCES public.cdf (reg) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT rgpt_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (nome)
        REFERENCES public.cdf (nome) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Nas minhas entidades geradas pelo Hibernate minhas chaves estrangeiras de RGPT ficaram assim:
O Java:

```
public class Rgpt:

     private int idRgpt;
     private Cdf cdfByReg;
     private Cdf cdfByNome;
     private String entrada;
     private String saida;

    public Cdf getCdfByReg() {
        return this.cdfByReg;
    }

    public void setCdfByReg(Cdf cdfByReg) {
        this.cdfByReg = cdfByReg;
    }
    public Cdf getCdfByNome() {
        return this.cdfByNome;
    }

    public void setCdfByNome(Cdf cdfByNome) {
        this.cdfByNome = cdfByNome;
    }
```

E o XML:

```
<class name="DAO.entity.Rgpt" table="rgpt" schema="public" optimistic-    lock="version">
    <id name="idRgpt" type="int">
        <column name="id_rgpt" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="cdfByReg" class="DAO.entity.Cdf" fetch="select">
        <column name="reg" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="cdfByNome" class="DAO.entity.Cdf" fetch="select">
        <column name="nome" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

O problema é quando eu vou fazer a consulta HQL e ele dá um erro muito estranho:
Consulta:

```
final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
String query = "from Rgpt as r where r.cdfByReg.reg= 54 and DATE(r.data) = '" + d.getDiaMesAno(data) + "'";
Query q = session.createQuery(query);
Rgpt rgpt = (Rgpt) q.uniqueResult();
```

ERRO:

> Hibernate: select rgpt0_.id_rgpt as id_rgpt1_1_, rgpt0_.reg as
>   reg2_1_, rgpt0_.nome as nome3_1_, rgpt0_.em as em4_1_, rgpt0_.ema as
>   ema5_1_, rgpt0_.sm as sm6_1_, rgpt0_.sma as sma7_1_, rgpt0_.et as
>   et8_1_, rgpt0_.eta as eta9_1_, rgpt0_.st as st10_1_, rgpt0_.sta as
>   sta11_1_, rgpt0_.eadd as eadd12_1_, rgpt0_.sadd as sadd13_1_,
>   rgpt0_.just as just14_1_, rgpt0_.data as data15_1_, rgpt0_.sem as
>   sem16_1_, rgpt0_.tdia as tdia17_1_, rgpt0_.ttaj as ttaj18_1_,
>   rgpt0_.dif as dif19_1_, rgpt0_.vt as vt20_1_, rgpt0_.bn as bn21_1_,
>   rgpt0_.grat_integral as grat_in22_1_, rgpt0_.grat_metade as
>   grat_me23_1_, rgpt0_.vr as vr24_1_, rgpt0_.va_integral as
>   va_inte25_1_, rgpt0_.va_metade as va_meta26_1_ from public.rgpt rgpt0_
>   where (rgpt0_.reg=? )and(DATE(rgpt0_.data)='23/03/2017' ) mar 23, 2017
>   4:54:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
>   logExceptions WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22003 mar 23, 2017 4:54:44
>   PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: Valor inválido para tipo int : ESTER

De alguma forma ele está pegando o `nome`(varchar) no lugar do `reg`(int), mas as referências a princípio parecem corretas.

Alguém sabe me dizer se tem algo errado na minha consulta ou código?
Grata!

Comment: Qual o código/mapeamento da entidade `Cdf`?